# How to use NavigationDestinationLink to go to another View?

Tags: swiftui

I wanted to use NavigationDestinationLink to go to another SwiftUI view but it does not works.

here you can see my code for the button item that I want to send me to the page I wanted but it does not works

```
var body: some View {

    Button(action: {
            if self.type == "origin"{
                NavigationDestinationLink(SelectDestination(), isDetail: true)
            } else if self.type == "destination"{

                NavigationDestinationLink(TravelCostPage())
            }
        print("Button Clicked")
    }) {
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            VStack {

                Text(title)
                    .bold()
                    .color(.black)

                    Text("توضیحات")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .color(.gray)

                    }
                    Image("grayStarIcon")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)

                        }.padding()
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
                    }


}
```

Comment: So what does it do?

Comment: Please include the full code of your view, and anything needed so people can actually test your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct object to do that is the `NavigationLink`. With `NavigationLink` you can control the navigation. It's important to notice that `NavigationLink` works only inside the `NavigationView`.

So, when you need to move the navigation to another view, you have to use just a `NavigationLink` containing a `Text` or some other non interactive view. The view defined inside the `NavigationLink` will work as a `Button`:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
    Text("click me")
}
```

Advanced example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeButton<Content>: View where Content: View {

    init(destination: Content, icon: String, title: String, description: String, color: Color, width: Length = .zero) {
        self.destination = destination
        self.icon = icon
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
    }

    let destination: Content
    let icon: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let color: Color
    let width: Length

    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
            Group {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(color)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)

                    Text(icon)
                        .font(.system(size: 55))
                        .offset(x: -25, y: 20)
                }.offset(x: 12.5, y: 0)

                VStack {
                    Text(title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .accentColor(.black)
                    Text(description)
                        .accentColor(.black)
                }.padding(.top, 0)
            }
            .frame(width: width == .zero ? nil : width)
            .padding(.top, 30)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .padding(.leading, 45)
            .padding(.trailing, 45)

        }
        .background(
            Color.white
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .shadow(color: Color.lightGray, radius: 20))

    }

}
```